# firebase snapshot not getting currentUser

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

i am trying to get current user in console but getting undefined in react-native. firebase 8.3 it is.
this is my firebase init

```
import firebase from "firebase";
// import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
const firebaseConfig = {
  //api
};
// Initialize Firebase
const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export default firebase;
```

this is action code , which is same as docs in internet

```
 firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("user")
      .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.exists) {
          console.log(snapshot.data());
          dispatch({ type: USER_STATE_CHANGE, currentUser: snapshot.data() });
        } else {
          console.log("does not exist, console from action ");
        }
```

and here is my redux store code, which is more doubtful in my knowledge

```
const store = createStore(Reducers, applyMiddleware(thunk))
 return (
      <Provider style={styles.center} store={store}>
       <Main/>
      </Provider>
    );
```

and main.js

```
function Main(props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    props.fetchUser();
  }, []);
  if (props.currentUser == undefined) {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>No Data</Text>
      </View>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{props.currentUser.name} is logged in now !</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    currentUser: state.user.currentUser,
  };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    fetchUser: () => dispatch(fetchUser()),
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main);
```

Comment: currentUser may be null if you are not logged in. Please check it and tell me if it is not working.

Comment: i am logged in and getting does not exist, console from action

Comment: actually problem was collection name, it was users not user.

Comment: @HowtoProgram Is your issue resolved by changing from "user" to "users"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess (it is hard to be certain from the fragments of code you shared) is that the code that loads the user data from Firestore runs when the page/app loads, and that Firebase isn't done restoring the current user when it runs.

When the page/app loads, Firebase automatically restores the user credentials from local storage. This requires it to call the server though (amongst others to see if the account has been disabled), which may take some times. While this call is going on, your main code continues, and the value of `firebase.auth().currentUser` is `null` at this point.

So if you don't synchronize your code that loads the user profile to Firebase''s restore actions, you will end up loading the data too early, when the user hasn't been re-signed yet.

The solution is to listen for auth state changes, and respond to those, instead of assuming that `firebase.auth().currentUser` is always correct. For an example of how to do this, see the first code snippet in the Firebase documentation on [getting the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user):

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
    var uid = user.uid;
    //  This is where you can load the user profile from Firestore
    // ...
  } else {
    // User is signed out
    // ...
  }
});
```